# How effective is ajaxcrawling compared to serverside created website SEO?

Tags: ajax, seo, client

I'm looking for real world experiences in regards to ajaxcrawling:

http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/index.html

I'm particularly concerned about the infamous Gizmodo failure of late, I know I can find them via Google now, but it's not clear to me how effective this method of ajaxcrawling is in comparison to serverside generated sites is.
I would like to make a wiki that lives mostly on the client side, and which is populated by ajax json. It just feels more fluid, and I think it would be a pluspoint over my competition. (wikipedia, wikimedia)
Obviously, for a wiki it's incredibly important to have working SEO.

I would be very happy for any experiences you have had dealing with clientside development.

My research shows that the general consensus on the web right now is, that you should absolutely avoid doing ajax sites unless you don't care about SEO (for example, a portfolio site, a corporate site etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, these SEO problems arise when you have a single page that loads content dynamically based on sophisticated client-side behavior. Spiders aren't always smart enough to know when JavaScript is being injected, so if they can't follow links to get to your content, most of them won't understand what's going on in a predictable way, and thus won't be able to fullly index your site.

If you could have the *option* of unique URLs that lead to static content, even if they all route back to a single page by a URL rewriting scheme, that could solve the problem. Also, it will yield huge benefits down the road when you've got a lot of traffic -- the whole page can be cached at the web server/proxy level, leading to less load on your servers.

Hope that helps.

Comment: If I understand correctly, I don't have any SEO problems as long as every page on my site is reachable by an absolute URL? Example: Someone visits my mainpage and I have an ajax call in there that loads json data and assembles it via client side templating. Are crawlers able to read that or do they just read html?

Comment: @Blub: If you want it to be indexed predictably, those URLs need to lead to static content. Otherwise some spiders might work but others won't understand what's going on.

Comment: @Blub: It can definitely work with Google though, here's a link: http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/docs/getting-started.html

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "routing back to a single page via URL rewriting". Where/how/why would it produce less load?

Comment: @Blub: This is a simplistic overview of a big topic, but if a certain URL always produces the same HTML, you can output cache it at the web server/proxy level. When you serve cached content it comes right out of RAM, whereas when a normal request is served there is generally disk IO, database hits, etc. Everything goes a lot faster and you can serve many times the number of requests you could handle otherewise. When you finally do have to scale, caching helps you scale out by adding more cheap web servers instead of figuring out how to get the DB to scale up... That kind of thing.